# Symfony 4/5 медленная инициализация

Tags: php, symfony4, symfony5

Есть два проекта один на 4 второй на 5 версии. В обоих профайлер периодически показывает медленную загрузку, вместо 40-50мс выдает больше 1000мс. Чую, что кэш, но никак не могу нагуглить что это точно и какие методики и практики есть с прогревом, что бы юзер никогда не видел долгую сборку.

Comment: Периодически это как часто? Раз в несколько часов или дней, если подряд обновлять страницу, то всегда быстро или иногда бывает медленно? Замерьте скорость в prod окружении

Comment: А что вам показывает раздел Performance metrics??

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в деплое. Но для dev версии это норм. Надо у новой сборки проекта прогревать кеш через команду, а потом менять симлинк для пользователей

```
bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```

А вообще посмотрите про жизненный цикл деплоя. Разберите тот же deployer